# Pass an image to REST with POST API Call in flutter

Tags: image, api, flutter, dart

I am trying to pass an image that is taken from either camera or picked from the gallery and pass it to the backend using a POST API call.
I am using image_picker plugin for flutter to access the image from camera and and gallery.

following is what I tried.

1. get the image file (from file path) in file format.
2. decrease the size of the image into a smaller value (uses flutter_image_compress library for this).
3. convert the result into a base64 string value or as form data and set it to the field in request body.

I will provide what I tried from the flutter code end for the above approach. please can anyone guide me am I doing this right or is there a better way to achieve this?

***Pick image from camera***

```
 Future _getImageFromCamera() async {
    PickedFile petImage = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera,maxHeight: 1000);
var _imageURITemp = File(petImage.path);
    final filePath = _imageURITemp.absolute.path;

final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.jp'));
    final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
    final outPath = "${splitted}${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";

    final compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        filePath,
        outPath,
        minWidth: 1000,
        minHeight: 1000,
        quality: 50);
//
setState(() {
var str = compressedImage.path.split('/');
      _imageURI = str[str.length - 1] as IO.File;
}
```

**Uploading with the POST method***

```
String base64Image;
    if(_imageURI != null) {
List<int> imageBytes = _imageURI.readAsBytesSync();
      base64Image = base64.encode(imageBytes);
//
var data = {
      'user_email': userEmail,
      'user_token': userToken,
      'pet': {
        "age": petAgeController.text,
        "birth_date": bdate,
        'eatbone': ,
        'ideal_weight': petIdealWeightController.text,
        'image': base64Image,
        'name': petNameController.text,
        "sex": _petSex,
        'weight': petWeightController.text,
        'guideline_id': '1',
        'activity_level_id': '2',
        'breed_id': '12',
        'user_id': userID,
      }
    };

    // final PET.PetCreate
    final pet = await CallApi().createThePet(data, 'pets/create')
}
```

Comment: So... what is your problem?

Comment: my problem is am I doing anything wring here? and is there a much better way to do this ? I am learning by trying with this image uploading in flutter.

Comment: I would really like to know. 
to pick and image from camera or gallery, to reduce its original size, and then upload it using api . 

I am confused in this file format and base64 string conversion. 
should I do both ? or not and how?